# "Schoolwide" or "School-wide"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

No dictionary seems to give me the same answer. Is this one word (schoolwide)? Is it two words (school wide)? Or is it "school-wide"?

Comment: If no two dictionaries gives you the same answer, isn’t that an indication that there is no single correct answer?  You should look at the examples from Josh's ngram search.

Comment: For a stronger and easier-to-answer question, please cite what references you've consulted and what they've told you.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of ***[-wide](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-wide)*** as a suffix referring to the whole of (something) dates back to Old English:

> - As a second element in compounds (such as nationwide, worldwide) meaning "extending through the whole of," is is from late Old English.

Etymonline

***[Schoolwide](https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&hl=it&biw=768&bih=909&ei=YEVgWJeYKYz3wQKsm4-4DQ&q=schoolwide%20meaning&oq=schoolwide%20meaning&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0i7i30i19k1.471727.471727.0.473030.1.1.0.0.0.0.147.147.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..0.1.146.n0Ovg3Glp8k)*** meaning  occurring or extending throughout a school in mainly found as a single word (see ***[Ngram)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=school%20wide%2Cschoolwide%2Cschool-wide&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cschool%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cschoolwide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cschool%20-%20wide%3B%2Cc0).***