# Usage of wide as a suffix

Tags: adjectives, suffixes

I've looked for the subject, but I don't find a comprehensive answer. I've checked Fowler's MEU, but I'm not happy with the answers I find because I don't find the precise point I'm looking for, so I asking for help here.

**May we add "wide" to any noun?** For example, if I want to refer to an organization like a bank, may I write "bankwide", "bank-wide", or "bank wide". Are there any specific rules about it?

Could "at large" be a substitute (depending on context of course)? For example, the document was distributed to the the main office, and the bank at large (or bankwide).

Comment: Thank you
No, I'm asking about using wide like in "worldwide".

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/365176

Answer (score 2):

From Collins Dictionary:

***[-wide as a suffix:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wide_2)***

> ***-wide*** combines with nouns to form adjectives which indicate that something exists or happens throughout the place or area that the noun refers to.
>
> - ...a Europe-wide conference on security and cooperation.
> - Is the problem one that's industry-wide?
>
> ***-wide*** also combines to form adverbs.
>
> - Employers want to be sure recruits understand business Europe-wide.
> - Country-wide, a total of 22 political parties are competing for the voters' allegiance.

As for [bankwide](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bankwide%2Cbank%20wide%2C%20bank-wide&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbankwide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbank%20wide%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbank%20-%20wide%3B%2Cc0) (bank wide, bank-wide) there are some usage examples available:

From [Securities Activities of Banks](https://books.google.it/books?id=NlgXPmoWy-sC&pg=SA6-PA89&dq=%22bank%20wide%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjagu39ltndAhVCBSwKHVJ2Dj4Q6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=%22bank%20wide%22&f=false) :

> The aggregate percentage is “the mean of the bank's yearly ***bank-wide compensation*** percentage for the immediately preceding year and the bank's yearly bank-wide compensation percentage for the year immediately preceding that year.” A bank's yearly “bank-wide compensation...

From [SEC docket](https://books.google.it/books?id=B-DlF4TdW2kC&q=%22bankwide%22&dq=%22bankwide%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG456amNndAhUQYxoKHXLGCBwQ6AEISTAH):

> The “aggregate relationship-total compensation percentage" of a bank operating under ***the bankwide approach*** would be calculated in a similar manner as the “ relationship-total compensation percentage” of an account under the ...

Answer (score 1):

The still productive suffix *-wide* can be attached to nouns that denote a discrete unit, whether social, geographic, or even textual, which has identifiable sub-units included in the scope of the modifier thus created. They may range from commonly used words — districtwide, citywide, regionwide, statewide, nationwide, worldwide — to ad hoc coinages or jargon limited to a particular group.

[image]
[<sub>*Source: Boulevard Appreciation Neighborhood Association, Schenectady NY*</sub>](http://banaschenectady.org/neighborhood-wide-garage-sale/)

> Community organizations face a major challenge in securing what they need to fund their own operations while pursuing a [*neighborhood-wide*](https://books.google.de/books?id=np_zz87OKm0C&pg=PA63&dq=neighborhood-wide&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbzMLQmNndAhUGyKQKHaclApQQ6AEIMjAC) plan.  — David J. Wright, *It Takes a Neighborhood: Strategies to Prevent Urban Decline*, 2001, 63.
>
> A [*district-wide*](https://books.google.de/books?id=f7FoDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA287&dq=district-wide&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ5szkm9ndAhUsposKHWpMBxUQ6AEIUTAJ) approach allows individual property owners to pursue more comprehensive measures and also take into account social and economic criteria with respect to the buildings most in need of refurbishment. — Peter Droege,*Urban Energy Transition: Renewable Strategies for Cities and Regions*, 2018.

Here, *district* is the translation of the German *Bezirk*, an official district within a city.

> Short-term, negligible, [*parkwide*](https://books.google.de/books?id=Ozg3AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA71&dq=parkwide&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi34aikl9ndAhWyp4sKHfokCVcQ6AEIMjAD), adverse effects would occur when park staff relocate equipment during flood events. — Herbert Hoover National Historic Site, 2006.

In these nursing contexts, *housewide* means ‘hospital-wide’. For words not common to all speakers and thus less likely to have a dictionary entry, hyphenation may vary.

> This exploratory quantitative research study focused on a [*house wide*](https://books.google.de/books?id=NhNtAQAACAAJ&dq=housewide&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS0Y3kmdndAhVstIsKHY1eDHgQ6AEIJjAA) hospital Registered Nurse float pool and its impact on nurse job satisfaction.  — Megan E. Duffy, *Effects of a House Wide Hospital Registered Nurse Float Pool*, 2010.
>
> To facilitate completion of the staging process for over 700 Registered Nurses, the Implementation Workgroup recommended establishment of both [*house-wide*](https://books.google.de/books?id=Lyo50PYr3kUC&pg=PA102&dq=housewide&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS0Y3kmdndAhVstIsKHY1eDHgQ6AEIPDAE) panels and unitbased panels.  — Barbara Haag-Heitman,  *Clinical Practice Development Using Novice to Expert Theory*, 1999.
>
> This “buy-in” created a common [*housewide*](https://books.google.de/books?id=xSN1BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA354&dq=housewide&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS0Y3kmdndAhVstIsKHY1eDHgQ6AEIQjAF) standard for pain identification and documentation, as well as a system-wide approach to pain management.  — Debra Mark, *Integrating Evidence into Practice for Impact*, 2014.

The suffix can also serve at various levels of an organization, including groupwide, teamwide, chapterwide, sectionwide, company-wide, corporate-wide, branchwide, businesswide, and, of course, *bankwide*.

> Concurrently with the preparation of the department plans, the task force developed plans on [*bankwide*](https://books.google.de/books?id=NuLzAAAAMAAJ&q=bankwide&dq=bankwide&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxv5Khm9ndAhXJposKHVAGAVM4FBDoAQgjMAA) matters— areas which were corporation-oriented rather than department-oriented. — *Burroughs Clearing House* 51 (1966), 25.

In these two examples, the suffix is applied to a chapter in a law code and a virtual book file composed of individual files in a software program:

> Current Section 5324(c), '“Prohibitions Against Regulating Operations and Charges,” is moved to Section 5334, “Administrative Provisions,” as a new Subsection (b). It is appropriate to house this prohibition in the “Administrative Provisions”section and make it expressly applicable [*chapter-wide*](https://books.google.de/books?id=MQIF3Z3Wu90C&pg=PA41&dq=%22chapter-wide%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4iYu0n9ndAhWHtosKHXCiCAYQ6AEIKjAB), rather than on capital projects only. — *Amending Chapter 53 of Title 49, United States Code*
>
> **Book-Wide Settings.**  After you put your files together into a book file, *[book-wide](https://books.google.de/books?id=uQ6pcqD6VV8C&pg=PA325&dq=%22book-wide%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHjaXVoNndAhVSpIsKHWVEC08Q6AEIRjAI)* command settings take precedence over the original individual file settings for the selected book files. — Lisa Jahred, *FrameMaker 6: Beyond the Basics*, 2001, 325.

While *[noun] at large* can sometimes substitute for *[noun]-wide*, it lacks the economy and flexibility of the suffixed word.  A notice inviting students to a schoolwide dance, for instance, would seem overly formal if it were called “a dance for the school at large.”